# Verify connection to server in a SPA

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, websocket

I'm developing a AngularJS driven SPA. I want to show a fullscreen overlay saying something like "Sorry - Server is not available atm" as soon as the connection between client and server is interrupted.

So I wrote a simple `while(true)` loop which is basically just calling `/api/ping` which always returns `true`. When there is no http response tho, then the message shall appear.

I don't like this approach since it creates a lot of overhead. Especially considering mobile connections.

So what would be a decent solution for my case?
I could imagine work with a websocket and an `onInterrupted` (or similar) event.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when an HTTP endpoint is offline you'll receive a `HTTP/404 Not found` status code.

I would say that it should be better wait for the error rather than querying the server overtime to check if it's online or not.

[Use Angular `$http` provider's interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to catch all unsuccessful HTTP status codes and perform an action when you catch one like showing notification to the user to notify that there's no connection available to the server or the server is offline.

Answer (score 0):

With WebSockets you still need to have some sort of ping mechanism, since there is functionally no difference between an inactive/very slow connection and a dropped connection.

Having said that, the overhead regarding wire traffic is much lower, since no HTTP headers are sent on each request, and this will result in lower processing overheads as well.